# 0xC0000005: Access Violation. when working with a lot of points

Tags: visual-c++, access-violation

I must use an old and crappy VC6.0 software.

This part of code process points, for a kind of 3D printer.
When I got a lot of points, (>2 000 000), it fails with "0xC0000005: Access Violation"

I'm really stuck, I have no idea how to fix this. The code is not from me.
Could it be too much malloc, with memory leaks ?

```
P_NOEUDP cstr_noeudp()
{
  P_NOEUDP N;

  N=(P_NOEUDP) malloc(sizeof(NOEUDP)); 
  N->classe=NULL; //Here it is 0xC0000005: Access Violation.
  N->face=NULL;
  N->arete_isolee=NULL;
  N->critere=NULL;
  N->data_list=NULL;
  return(N);
}
```

This is called in :

```
P_SLICE_POINT tpp_Slice_Point_Cstr()
{
    P_SLICE_POINT pSPt;
    pSPt = (P_SLICE_POINT) malloc(sizeof(SLICE_POINT));
    pSPt->Node=cstr_noeudp();
    pSPt->Edge=NULL;
    return pSPt;
}
```

Here are the headers :

```
struct S_NOEUDP
  {
    int          numero;
    double       courbureGaus;
    double       X[3];
    CLASSEMENT   *classe;
    LISTE        *face;
    LISTE        *arete_isolee;
    LISTE        *critere;
    P_DATA_LISTE data_list;
  };

typedef struct S_NOEUDP NOEUDP;
typedef NOEUDP *P_NOEUDP;

struct S_CLASSEMENT
  {
    int    type;
    int    etat;
    int    situation;
  };

typedef struct S_CLASSEMENT CLASSEMENT;
typedef CLASSEMENT *P_CLASSEMENT;

struct S_LISTE
  {
    int    type_liste;
    int    type_occurence;
    void   *occurence;
    int    type_reference;
    void   *reference;
    struct S_LISTE *svt;
    struct S_LISTE *prec;
  };

typedef struct S_LISTE LISTE;
typedef LISTE *P_LISTE;

struct S_DATA_LISTE
  {
   P_LISTE      data_liste;
     };

typedef struct S_DATA_LISTE DATA_LISTE ;
typedef DATA_LISTE  *P_DATA_LISTE ;

typedef struct S_SLICE_POINT SLICE_POINT;
typedef SLICE_POINT *P_SLICE_POINT;
```

Comment: A crappy compiler doesn't prevent you from checking for errors.  You must check the return value of malloc().  A NULL means the show is over, you have no more memory.

Answer (score 0):

So, crappy code, full of memory leaks and no error control...

What's happening next :

- Memory fills up because of memory leaks (malloc without freeing)
- Memory usage reachs the 32 bit limits, could no more allocate
- Code hangs, and we don't know why, because there's no malloc return check